# How does assignment into function return value work?

Tags: r

I have stumbled apon this code:

```
colnames(dataFrame) <- c("firstCol", "secondCol")
```

which renames columns of given dataframe dataFrame. What is happening there? How can I possibly assign something to return value?

[Corresponding R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=SJpEfp16)

Comment: There are only a few functions `func<-`.

Comment: See the [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1:

```
> `setvalue<-` <- function(x,value) value
> x <- 0
> setvalue(x) <- 1
> x
[1] 1
```

Example 2:

```
> `add<-` <- function(x,value) x+value
> x
[1] 1
> add(x) <- 3      # x <- x+3
> x
[1] 4
```

Comment: What a wierd syntax sugar!